# Dell latitude E6430 not booting

Tags: laptop, memory, display, fan, capslock

One morning I woke up and my laptop was not able to turn on. Laptop's fan doesn't make sound, there's no display, power button is lighting and caps lock is flashing. Tried switching RAM, hold power button for 30 seconds, nothing worked.
(edit) After powering on laptop after 10 seconds it just shutdowns.

What could be the problem?

IT FIXED!!!
First I tried reseat lcd cable, and then I just spinned the AC adapter piece where it goes to laptop in the hole.

Comment: Remove battery, plug it in, and try starting it.

Comment: Still no changes.

Comment: Remove battery, hold the Power button down for a solid minute, then put the battery back in and try to fire it up again.

Comment: No fan means dead power supply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Dell it means [there is a memory error](https://www.dell.com/support/article/en-us/sln309632/a-reference-guide-for-latitude-notebook-and-tablet-diagnostic-indicators?lang=en)

(Scroll down the page to D-series Diagnostic LED's (Prior to 2008) and expand it.)

[image]

[Your full support page](https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/product/latitude-e6430/overview)