# Dell latitude e6430 wont turn on

Tags: laptop

When I try to turn my laptop on, the power button light is on, there's no fan working, no display, solid caps lock light and after like 10 seconds it turns off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dell latitude E6430 not booting](https://superuser.com/questions/1553256/dell-latitude-e6430-not-booting)

Answer (score 1):

Normally when turning on power you should hear fans spin up immediately and see a DELL logo on the screen during POST. If fans aren't working and you see nothing on screen (doesn't flicker, etc) it is likely mainboard is dead. It could also be a PSU issue.

Try removing the battery from the laptop and plug it into a power source. If you can, use a verified working power adapter. If you turn it on and it exhibits the same symptoms then it is likely the mainboard (motherboard) is dead.

If you are versed with disassembling laptops, I'd try to take it apart, clean out any dust/debris, make sure there's no obvious damage such as burst capacitors. If the laptop was physically dropped or had something spilled on it it's likely dead now.

Comment: In addition to the above, get a bootable USB key, insert the key and see if it is recognized when you try to start it.